# Blackberry OS 10 ignoring static routes

Tags: blackberry, static-routes

We are trying to get Blackberry 10 devices (include Z10, Q10, Playbook) to find devices on our corporate wan.  The end-user devices are on one subnet, while servers on another.  The server subnet is NOT accessible via the default route, so we push out static routes using DHCP option 121.  The windows workstation clients work great with this, but not the blackberrys.

Anyone know how to make the blackberrys use a static route?

Comment: This strikes me as you struggling mightily to *Do It Wrong* -- Either there is an existing route between your end-user-devices network and your servers (which should be handled by your routers), or your end user devices should be connecting via a VPN. Static routes are almost never the correct solution to a problem, and are especially heinous on mobile/portable devices...

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing something like pushing static routes instead of say...proper firewall rules between the server subnet and untrusted subnet?

Comment: These are both trusted subnets (this is within a corporate environment), there is no firewall inbetween, just routers.  Pushing routes via DHCP is actually the right/normal way to handle multiple routes (and it works fine with almost all of our servers, workstations, network devices, etc).  The BB OS is the first time we are encountering this.

Comment: Why do you have multiple routes in the first place. Why are you relying on clients for routing and not on your L3 devices?

Comment: We have the firewall (default route to outside), and three other subnets routing through a second router.  If we routed everything through the firewall we would overload that device.